# How import html in another html file like php include() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to include header and footer in all of my pages. I can include in php by using include() function. But I have only .html file. So is there any html markup to include another html file.

Comment: If your server supports it, you can use [Server Side Includes](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/includes.html)

Answer (score 2):

With jquery you can do an ajax request:

```
 $('footer').load('/yourPage.html', function () {
    //if you need to do something after
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using HTML Imports

```
<head>
  <link rel="import" href="/path/to/file/file.html">
</head>
```

And use it with:

```
var content = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]').import;
```

Comment: I tried it. But it hasn't rendered  in the browser. But has external file markups added in code view

Comment: @sasikumar you still have to insert the content into the dom somewhere. His code only stored it into the content variable. If you have a dom node use this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild if you have text, use .innerHTML.